# HP Z6 G4 Missing RAM in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a HP Z6 G4 workstation with 4x 64GB DIMMs. However, when I boot into Ubuntu 20.04, I only see a total of 64GB instead of the expected 256GB. I double-checked the DIMM placement and seating, and swapped DIMM modules for others but cannot get beyond 64GB. Can anyone help me diagnose this issue?

Comment: what does BIOS report

Comment: And what happens if you only put 2 in? And what does the label say on one of them?

Comment: The BIOS shows only 1 DIMM slot active. It sees the other DIMM slots are populated but sais the other 3 are DISABLED. If I run with 2 DIMMs then it still shows only 1 active and the other DISABLED. It recognizes a DIMM is plugged in but only the first slot is ACTIVE

Comment: Any further thoughts? Im still stuck on this issue.